# Using styled components with Typescript, prop does not exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Here is my styled component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { ComponentChildren } from 'app-types';

interface Props {
    children: ComponentChildren;
    emphasized: boolean;
}

const HeadingStyled = styled.h2`
    ${props => props.emphasized && css`
        display: inline;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 30px;
  `}
`;

const Heading = (props: Props) => (
    <HeadingStyled>
        {props.children}
    </HeadingStyled>
);

export default Heading;
```

I get warnings that:

- `Property 'emphasized' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, any>'.`
- `Cannot find name 'css'. Did you mean 'CSS'?`

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

- The styled component will have to specify the prop to pass to the component like `styled("h2")<IProps>`. You can read more about the pattern from [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#styling-components)
- `css` is not required here, it is added as a helper when you need to actually return CSS from a function. Check out [conditional rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502647/conditional-rendering-in-styled-components).

Taking these into account, the component becomes:

```
const HeadingStyled = styled("h2")<{emphasized: boolean}>`
  ${props => props.emphasized && `
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  `}
`;
```

[A use-case for `css`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#media-templates)

Comment: The documentation is different from your example and also the _use-case for css_ is not working any more. Could you please investigate? I am lost.

Comment: The typings has changed after I had written the answer, updated answer with the recent changes

Comment: I would just like to add another thing that was missing for me: you also need to pass the `emphasized` prop to `HeadingStyled`, like so: `<HeadingStyled emphasized={props.emphasized}> {props.children} </HeadingStyled>`. Might be obvious for some but wanted to point it out

Comment: @Agney I facing the same issue here is my code
` 
      import styled from 'styled-components';

      export const MainWrapper = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
     `;
`
getting type error 
**TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type ThemedStyledFunction<string, any, (i, never> | undefined' are callable.
Type 'undefined' has no call signatures**
when I use like this
but when I use like this **styled('div')** then it's working but It's will big change for me to do everywhere in project

Answer (score 14):

The previous answer worked for me, but just to add some information that was also helpful in my case:

> StyledComponents uses a "ThemedStyledFunction" interface that allows the user to define additional Prop Types.

That means you could create an interface like:

```
interface IHeadingStyled {
   emphasized: boolean;
}
```

And use it on the component:

```
const HeadingStyled = styled("h2")<IHeadingStyled>`
  ${props => props.emphasized && `
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  `}
`;
```

(Which is a cleaner way to implement what @BoyWithSilverWings suggested, in case you have multiple props)

---

Check this discussion for more complete information:

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1428#issuecomment-358621605

Answer (score 6):

This solution also works with emotion, maybe cause both of them uses stylis as a preprocessor?

```
interface ButtonProps {
  width: string;
}

const Button = styled("button")<ButtonProps>((props) => {
  return `width: ${props.width};`;
});
```

or different flavour same thing

```
interface ButtonProps {
  width: string;
}

const Button = styled("button")<ButtonProps>`
  width: ${props => props.width};
`;
```

or

```
interface ButtonProps {
  width: string;
}

const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  width: ${props => props.width};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using styled components in a diferent sheet, I was having the same error.

I had to do this in index.tsx:

```
 export interface RadioBoxProps {
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Then, in the styling sheet:

```
 import { RadioBoxProps } from "./index";

export const RadioBox = styled.button<RadioBoxProps>`

background: ${(props) => props.isActive ? '#eee' : 'transparent'};

`
```

In the tutorial I was watching, the person passes without exporting the interface and importing in the styling sheet. For him,  it was working just fine. However, for me I wasn't and just worked when I did what I shown above.

Answer (score -1):

```
   /** In App.tsx **/

      <div className="App">
          <Button>Register</Button>
          <Button primary="primary">Register</Button>
     </div>


    /*In your functional component*/
    import styled from "styled-components";
    
    interface IButtonPropsType {
      primary: string;
    }
    
    export const Button = styled.button<IButtonPropsType>`
    background: ${(props) => (props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white")}
    color: ${(props) => (props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred")}
    font-size: 1.5em
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    border: 2px solid palevioletred;
    border-radius: 3px;
    `;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).