# Typescript says a prop does not exist on a component I wrapped with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react and along with styled-components. I am wrapping the Tab component with styled-components to customize its look. Here is that code

```
const CustomTab = styled(Tab)<{props: TabProps}>`
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

As you can see I am trying to specify that the props for `CustomTab` will be the same props as the `Tab` component. I did this based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405602/6356919) answer.

The problem is that typescript still seems to think that `Menu` props does not exits on my `CustomTab` component.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `const CustomTab = styled(Tab)<TabProps>`

You basically defined your props as an object that looks like this: `{props: {TabProps}}`