# Props doesn't exist? Using styled-component and typeScript, already implement `interface`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

this is my styled component

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

const CategoryButton = styled(Button).attrs({
  variant: 'outlined',
})`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: ${theme.spacing(2)}px ${theme.spacing(4)}px;
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.selected ? theme.colors.primary.main : theme.colors.background};
    color: ${(props) =>
      props.selected ? theme.colors.background : theme.colors.primary.main};
    border-color: ${(props) =>
      props.selected ? theme.colors.primary.main : '#c8c8c8'};
  `}
`;
```

it returns an error that said

- `Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'ThemeProps<DefaultTheme>'`

I've tried to implement the suggestion on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405602/11201996) to specify the props to pass to component

```
interface CategoryButton {
  selected?: boolean;
}

const CategoryButton = styled(Button).attrs({
  variant: 'outlined',
})<CategoryButton>`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    ...
  `}
`;
```

Nevertheless, the same error still appears. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in `selected` in `CategoryButton`  like this. It works same as props passing to child:

```
<CategoryButton selected={true}/>
```