# React Js Button Toggle/ Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

my style
    import React from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';

```
export const DivMenuButton = styled.div`
    border: 0px;
    backgroundColor: #000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
`;
```

my return:

```
import { DivMenuButton } from './styles';

export default function Menu() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(0); 
    const handleClick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setOpen(!open);
    };
    return (
      <DivMenuButton>
        <Button
          style={{ margin:0, padding: 0, height: "30px", width: "100%", borderRadius:'0px' }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Button
        </Button>
      </DivMenuButton>  
    );
}
```

I would also like to know how I could do the following:

I have a state open

my div will start with 400 px
clicking the button will get it 30px
but I don't know how I can do this with styled components

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502795/11599909)

Comment: there he went on to active = prop active
can i create any name?
how
open and prop open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use styled-components [props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

**Try this:**

```js
export const DivMenuButton = styled.div`
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #000; // was wrong syntax
    height: 400px;
    width: ${props => props.width}
`;

export default function Menu() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); 
    const handleClick = e => {
      // e.preventDefault(); no need 
      setOpen(!open);
    };

    return (
      <DivMenuButton width={open ? '30px' : '400px'}>
        <button
          style={{ margin:0, padding: 0, height: "30px", width: "100%", borderRadius:'0px' }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Button
        </button>
      </DivMenuButton>   
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello this way when I click my button the div would continue with the same prop and would not change. example she starts with 400 height i clicking a button she would go to 40px

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand would you explain more? The main question was about changing the div width not height?