# conditionally show after pseudo element react and styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using react with styled components and I have a resizable panel and one of the panels contains an iframe. I was trying to fix a drag issue by using an after pseudo element and setting a backdrop-filter conditionally however having the after element always steals the click events. Is there a way to conditionally show the '&:after' element and not just the backdrop-filter?

```js
export const IframeWrapper = styled(FlexColumn)`
  justify-content: flex-end;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    backdrop-filter: ${props => props.isDragging && 'blur(5px)'};
  }
`;
```

Comment: Same way you did for `backdrop-filter`?

Comment: Do you know the correct syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64807065/12667595

Comment: Sorry that link does not help. I mean specifically to conditionally render the &:after element

Comment: Why it doesn't help? It does exactly what you are after - `conditionally render the &:after element`.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. The answer you linked to didn't actually solve my issue but the one above it does so...close enough. I'll post my working code in case it helps anyone else. Thanks @MrT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working code with help from Mr T:

```js
export const IframeWrapper = styled(FlexColumn)`
  justify-content: flex-end;

  ${({ isDragging }) => isDragging &&
    css`
      &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
      }
    `
  }
`;
```