# Understanding css helper function in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Styled components has a helper [css](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) function. But I don't understand when should I used it.

For example this is their example where they use it:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const complexMixin = css`
  color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
`

const StyledComp = styled.div`
  /* This is an example of a nested interpolation */
  ${props => (props.complex ? complexMixin : 'color: blue;')};
`
```

But if we take similar example from docs here they don't use it:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  /* Adapt the colors based on primary prop */
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

Their description is also not clear and is confusing me:

> A helper function to generate CSS from a template literal with
> interpolations. You need to use this if you return a template literal
> with functions inside an interpolation due to how tagged template
> literals work in JavaScript.

Can someone help explain why we need it?

PS this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502795/3963067) also doesn't use it

Answer (score 3):

I use the css function when I create variants for a component:

that is variant switcher:

```
const sizeVariant: Record<NonNullable<StyledLogoProps['size']>, ReturnType<typeof css>> = {
  small: css`
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
  `,
  regular: css`
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
  `,
};
```

that is component was created by 'styled-components':

```
interface StyledLogoProps {
  size: 'small' | 'regular';
}

export const StyledLogo = styled.div<StyledLogoProps>`
  ${({ size }) => sizeVariant[size]}
`;
```

and this is the use in the react:

```
<>
  <StyledLogo size="regular" />
  <StyledLogo size="small" />
</>
```

quite a useful thing